# python formatting issue, trying to print but come up short

Tags: python

[image]

My code that does this:

```
        print(count,"\t",monthlyPayment,"\t",interest,"\t",loanAmount)
```

How can make this more neat and cleaner i am not sure why they aren't aligned? Please guide? Want this in tabular form

Comment: The word `"payment"` is long enough that it breaks through the next tabstep (generally 8 characters). Instead of using tabs, use spaces.

Comment: If you don't want to write your own tabulation logic, you can drop in [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) to do it for you. `pip install tabulate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [format()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=format#format). For example:

```
print('{:7d} {:10d} {:15.2f} {:15.2f}'.format(count, monthlyPayment, interest, loanAmount))
```

Here `d` stands for decimal integer and `f` for floating point numbers. The numbers are the width. For example `7d` makes a seven places wide integer:

```
    3000
```

and `15.2f` an floating number with a total width of 15 and 2 decimals:

```
         1000.00
```

Example output for:

```
print('{:7d} {:10d} {:15.2f} {:15.2f}'.format(1, 300, 416.67, 99915.67))
```

is:

```
      1        300          416.67        99915.67
```

Comment: Can you explain the different formating numbers used?

Comment: Thank you clean and perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Formatting by tabs is historically tricky. As soon as one of your fields becomes longer than a tabstep, your whole formatting breaks. In this case, that field is the header `"payment"`.

Rather than using tabs, you could calculate the column width (in characters) and create a `str.format` formatting that matches. I'm assuming you have data like

```
data = [(1, 500, 416.67, 99916.67),
        (2, 500, 416.32, 99832.99),
        ...]
header = [("month", "payment", "interest", "balance")]
```

And are printing with:

```
for line in header + data:
    print("\t".join(line))
```

Instead, you'll need to run through your data an extra time. Once to establish column width, then once to print.

```
colwidths = []
for column in zip(*(header + data)):
    colwidths.append(len(str(max, column, key=lambda s: len(str(s)))) + 1)
    # the `+ 1` in this case being the column margin

formatting = "".join(r"{{:{}}}".format(width for width in colwidths))

for line in header + data:
    print(formatting.format(*line))
```

---

Alternatively you could have `tabulate` do the job for you. This is a 3rd-party module that's kept in the pypi package manager [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate). Install it with

```
pip install tabulate
```

Then use code like:

```
import tabulate

data = [(1, 500, 416.67, 99916.67),
        (2, 500, 416.32, 99832.99),
        ...]
header = [("month", "payment", "interest", "balance")]

print(tabulate.tabulate(data, headers=*header))
```